# Customizing ViewPager view indicator

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am a newbie in Android Development and I am working on a application that implements ViewPager. Now, I would like to know if there is a way to customize a little bit the tabs in the layout.xml file. What I am trying to do is to resize the tabs and change the color of indicator (Jellybean blue). Thank you!

[image: ViewPager tabs indicator]

Comment: You didn't explain whether the tabs are the result of `ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS` or a `TabPageIndicator`. However, if you just want to change the but keep the Holo style, the easiest solution is probably to generate the relevant assets using the [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.com/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). You can then grab the relevant resources from the resulting template.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit nine-patch PNGs named `vpi__tab_???_holo`. There are 6 of them for each screen density.